# What does "Be perfect" in Mathew 5:48 entail?

Tags: matthew, sermon-on-the-mount

What, exactly, does Jesus mean when He says, «*Be perfect, therefore, as your heavenly Father is perfect*» in Matthew 5:48? Is this a reference to the preceding list (i.e. does it entail "turning the other cheek also", "handing over your coat as well", "going two miles instead of one", "not turning away from the one who wants to borrow from you", and "loving your enemies" from verses 38-47) or does it mean something else?